# How do I add an attribute + it's sortorder (position) to the product list collection?

Tags: database, collection, sql, product-collection

How do I add an attribute + it's sortorder (position) to the product list collection?

In the catalog category list we use 1 text attribute (brand) and 1 list attribute (size) .... for every product we have to use getAttribute() and getAttributetext() ....

BUt: how can I

1. add the brand attribute to the list collection?
2. add the size attribute + it's position (sort order) to the list collection?

Can this easily be added to the query? or how do I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php` to `\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php`

In the function `_getProductCollection` after the statement

```
$this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();
```

add below code.

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('brand')->addAttributeToSelect('size')->setOrder('size','DESC');
```

You can also override the `List` class by adding below code into a custom module's `config.xml`.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list>Custom_Module_Block_Product_List</product_list>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thx. This looks almost complete. But I don't see how we are retrieving the position column of the attribute

Comment: You mean you want to add position of options of the attribute size?

Comment: I eventually need to sort by the attribute position of the options. Yes.

Comment: Also does the query get the language specific version? And if not exist fallback to default/admin value. Seems difficult to do ....